# Issue with math.h

Tags: c, math

I am getting a really weird issue with my code.
I tried using clang and gcc, both tell me the same thing

```
init_twiddle.c:12:10: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'cosf' with type 'float (float)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          .re = cosf(primitive_root*i) ,
                ^
init_twiddle.c:12:10: note: include the header <math.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'cosf'
init_twiddle.c:13:10: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'sinf' with type 'float (float)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          .im = sinf(primitive_root*i)
                ^
init_twiddle.c:13:10: note: include the header <math.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'sinf'
2 warnings generated.
```

The code:

```c
// file: init_twiddle.c

#include "complex.h"
#include <math.h>

void init_twiddle1024(Complex__complex* twiddle) {
  int i,span ;
  // Init the twiddles
  for(span=1;span<=512;span<<=1) {
    float primitive_root = -Complex__pi/span ;
    for(i=0;i<span;i++) {
      Complex__complex t =
    {
     .re = cosf(primitive_root*i) ,
     .im = sinf(primitive_root*i)
    } ;
      twiddle[span+i] = t ;
    }
  }
}
```

```c
// file: complex.h

#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#include "stdbool.h"
#include "assert.h"
//#include "pervasives.h"
typedef struct Complex__complex {
  float re;
  float im;
} Complex__complex;

static const float Complex__pi = 3.141593;

#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

The command I use to compile:

```
gcc -I. -I$(heptc -where)/c/ -std=c99 -c init_twiddle.c
```

I am working on a project with some strange programming language which explain all the included directories.

Does someone have any idea of why I am getting those errors?

PS: note that it's not a linker issue but an issue at compile time.
It also does not seem to appear when I manually write the content of complex.h into the file

Comment: We need enough code to reproduce the error. If you can reproduce it without `complex.h`, please edit your question. If not, please include that code.

Comment: Do you have your own `math.h` file? Your `-I` options are providing directories to search for `<math.h>` before the system version.

Comment: Yes you're right the langage I use define its own math.h, which I include with the  -I$(heptc -where)/c/ thanks a lot, I think I can resolve this question know (didnt though to this because it is not my math.h)

Comment: Yes, your code works fine with the system `<math.h>` on Ubuntu, so it must be your custom `math.h`.

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved my issue, now I just need to find how to include de right math.h without removing the -I. Also I am very new to stack overflow, how should I mark this question as resolved ?

Comment: Answer yourself with an explanation and solution. Then accept that answer.

Comment: error just means your `cosf` and `sinf` are unknown so my bet is your `math.h` uses `sin,cos` names for it instead. so simply try to add `#define sinf(x) sin(x)` and the same for `cos` directly after including `math.h`

Answer (score 2):

It turned out Barmar was right. I was including a directory where a math.h already exists, thus leading to not including the libc one.
The faulty one was `-I$(heptc -where)/c/` for those who would have the same issue with the Heptagon langage.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: heh had the same weird error and it turned out the embedded board SDK support package also had a math.h in their libboard/include dir (which you have to have a -I setup to), which only defined 3 math functions and nothing else... :/

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Barmar, the issue is that in `$(heptc -where)/c/` there is already a math.h header defined which don't implement the function you want to use in this exemple.

Considering it's to compile with [Heptagon](https://gitlab.inria.fr/synchrone/heptagon) I would advise to copy the only file that is really useful in this case from `$(heptc -where)/c/` which is `pervasives.h` where you have your init_twiddle.c and since you are compiling with `-I.` it will then compile perfectly fine.